# Basename returns file name with additional "\r\r\r" in the end?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write simple shell script that clones a github repo then CDs into the folder. I have

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1 is github repo url
url=$1
reponame=$(basename $url)
git clone $url
echo $reponame
cd $reponame
```

Now when I run

```
bash deploy_app.sh https://github.com/username/reponame
```

It echoes the right $reponame but the next line returns this "cd: $'reponame\r\r\r\r': No such file or directory"

I have no idea where the "\r\r\r\r" part is coming from. It's not in the repo name and it's not part of $reponame when I just echo it. Any idea why this happens??

Comment: Replace the line `echo $reponame` with `printf "%q\n" "$reponame"` and observe what is printed out.

Comment: Your script file probably has DOS/Windows-style line endings; see ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *first* thing I would be looking at is your script itself, by doing something like:

```
od -xcb deploy_app.sh
```

and looking for any carriage return characters (<kbd>CR</kbd>, `^M`, `\r`, hex `0d`, or octal `015`) at the end of the `cd` line (or *any* line really).

That's because, if you *have* <kbd>CR</kbd> characters at the end, it will cause that problem (the `^M` characters below were entered with <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd><kbd>CTRL-M</kbd>):

```
pax:~> cd blah^M^M^M^M
-bash: cd: $'blah\r\r\r\r': No such file or directory
```

---

If there *are* <kbd>CR</kbd> characters in your file, you probably want to remove them, and check your line ending settings for `git` (assuming that file is *in* a repo) - this is a problem commonly caused by incorrect settings if you're updating your repo from both Windows and Unix.

If that file is not being "damaged" by `git`, you'll need to discover what *else* is putting those characters in.

---

And, as an aside, you wouldn't actually *see* whether the `reponame` had those characters with an `echo`, since echoing them would result in the actual characters, four "go to the start of the line" characters, then a "go to the next line" character. Hence there's no way to tell the difference just by looking, without pushing the output through a command like `od`.

Comment: Whereas it is true that those characters cannot be *seen* with a plain `echo $reponame`, they can be *seen* with a `printf ` like that: `printf "%q\n" "$reponame"`. Or even with an `echo`: `echo ${reponame@Q}`

Comment: Thanks!! I had the script inittally written in window then upload to the linux server. I rewrote it with the Nano in the server directly and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure either, but try changing $reponame to "${reponame}" (with the double quotes) and see if it still happens.